# How can i access the index at i from a forloop that is outside my onClickMethod?

Tags: android, for-loop, onclick

Im wondering how i can access the index at i from my forloop method in the code below that is outside my onClick method?
Im trying to get the index so i can set what activity is opened when the cardViews are clicked through my onClick method.

Code :

```
 private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //Create For loop to loop through all child items in grid
    for(int i=0; i<mainGrid.getChildCount();i++){
        //Casting to all cardView items
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Getting new Activity when cardView is clicked
                if(finalI=0){
                    Intent genre = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Genre.class);
                    startActivity(genre);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: if (finalI == 0) * . - I'm thinking the typo is causing your undesired result.

Comment: This isn't good practice. Use a `RecyclerView` with the `GridLayout`, and set the `onClick` in it's adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access index inside onClick method, Either it must be final or it should be global.

Since index is driving a loop, so it can't be final. The solution is **Make index global.**

Answer (score 0):

this is very bad practice. I'm sorry, but you should consider following better practices. Click listeners can be done through interfaces and put inside your adapter class and wired up in the bindView routine. Then you just implement your interface in the calling fragment or activity. Pass it as one of the parameters of the adapter.

Here is an example of a generic binding adapter that I use for most my recycler views if not all. And a grid is just another form of recycler view so i have also used it for that.

/**
 *
 * Created by App Studio 35 on 5/23/2017.
 */
public class BindingRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

```
/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MEMBERS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private static String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + BindingRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private int MODEL_TAG = -124;
private int MODEL_POSITION_TAG = -125;
private int mRowLayoutResourceId;
private int mBindingModelId;
private int mActionButtonId;
private boolean mHasActionButton;
private ObservableArrayList<T> mList;
private IBindingRecyclerView mIBindingRecyclerView;


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PROPERTIES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * This is now how the interface needs to be set. This is taken care of in the @BindingAdapter
 * method "bind:rcvInterface" (BindingAdapterMethods). I also decided to take care of setting the
 * rowLayoutResourceId here, more as a "might as well" sort of thing, but also preventing the chance
 * of a null ref exception if we were to use mIBindingRecyclerView.getRowLayoutResourceId() and
 * mIBindingRecyclerView was null. Same goes for bindingModelId.
 * @param iBindingRecyclerView
 */
public void setIBindingRecyclerView(IBindingRecyclerView iBindingRecyclerView) {
    mIBindingRecyclerView = iBindingRecyclerView;
    mRowLayoutResourceId = iBindingRecyclerView.getRowLayoutResourceId();
    mBindingModelId = iBindingRecyclerView.getBindingModelId();
    mActionButtonId = iBindingRecyclerView.getActionButtonResourceId();
    mHasActionButton = mActionButtonId > 0;

}
/**
 * This is how the list is set and any changes made will be notified here. If notifyDataSetChanged()
 * is not called here, then the view will not be updated with the list changes. Setting the list gets
 * taken care of in the @BindingAdapter method "bind:rcvList" (BindingAdapterMethods). Anytime the list
 * changes in the activity/fragment, it will trigger the "bind:rcvList" method, and that will call
 * setList(), thus updating the list and notifying data set changed which updates the view properly.
 * @param list
 */
public void setList(ObservableArrayList list) {
    mList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BASE CLASS OVERRIDES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public BindingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, mRowLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
    return new BindingHolder(viewDataBinding);

}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BindingHolder holder, int position) {
    T model = mList.get(position);
    holder.binding.setVariable(mBindingModelId, model);
    holder.binding.setVariable(BR.AMEnvironment, AMEnvironment.getInstance());
    holder.binding.getRoot().setTag(MODEL_TAG, model);
    holder.binding.getRoot().setTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG, position);
    holder.binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.binding.getRoot().setOnLongClickListener(this);

    if(mHasActionButton){
        View btnAction = holder.binding.getRoot().findViewById(mActionButtonId);
        btnAction.setTag(MODEL_TAG, model);
        btnAction.setTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG, position);
        btnAction_onClick(btnAction);

    }

    holder.binding.executePendingBindings();

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();

}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CLICK LISTENERS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mIBindingRecyclerView != null){
        T model = (T) v.getTag(MODEL_TAG);
        int position = (int) v.getTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG);
        mIBindingRecyclerView.onItemClick(model, position);

    }

}
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if(mIBindingRecyclerView != null){
        T model = (T) v.getTag(MODEL_TAG);
        int position = (int) v.getTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG);
        mIBindingRecyclerView.onItemLongClick(model, position);

    }

    return true;

}
public void btnAction_onClick(View btnAction){
    btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            T model = (T) v.getTag(MODEL_TAG);
            int position = (int) v.getTag(MODEL_POSITION_TAG);
            mIBindingRecyclerView.onActionItemClick(model, position);

        }
    });

}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SCOPED CLASSES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // MEMBERS
    public ViewDataBinding binding;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public BindingHolder(ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding) {
        super(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
        binding = viewDataBinding;

    }

}

}
```

Then in your class you could do:

```
extends BaseFragment implements IBindingRecyclerView

 /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BINDING ADAPTER OVERRIDES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public int getRowLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.card_person;

}
@Override
public int getBindingModelId() {
    return BR.personModel;

}
@Override
public void onItemClick(Object model, int position) {
    startViewIDsForPersonActivity((PersonModel) model);

}
@Override
public void onItemLongClick(Object model, int position) {
    final PersonModel personModel = (PersonModel) model;
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener delete = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            deletePerson(personModel);

        }
    };

    mIBaseActivityCallback.showDialogMessage(personModel.getFullName(), getString(R.string.confirm_delete_of_person), delete, cancel);

}
@Override
public void onActionItemClick(Object model, int position) {

}
@Override
public int getActionButtonResourceId(){
    return -1;
}
```

Of course this is overkill for you, so you could ditch the binding pieces and the action button wire up, but you should at least get the picture of using an interface for your click handling instead of what you are doing.